# Getting "MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS" when sending mail via SMTP

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, starttls

When using **JavaMail** to send a message via **SMTP (+STARTTLS)** the following exception is raised:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Multiple posts here (on stackoverflow) and elsewhere suggest that some properties for the mail transport session, namely

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","*");
```

play a role in solving this issue, but I have tried all combinations of those parameters (present / absent), and none of them solves the problem.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

---

**Additional Information / Details**:

Java version: 1.6.0

JavaMail version: 1.5.2

Properties for mail transport session:

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.host","XXX");
props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","*");
props.put("mail.smtp.user","XXX");
props.put("mail.smtp.password","XXX");
props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout","60000");
props.put("mail.smtp.timeout","600000");
props.put("mail.smtp.writetimeout","60000");
```

Debug output from JavaMail (before Exception is raised):

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.
MTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Mi
rosystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,
mtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax
mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "XXX", port 587, isSSL false
220 bsmtp.bon.at ESMTP (1)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "XXX", port: 587
EHLO ZZZ
250-bsmtp.bon.at
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 104857600
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "104857600"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Full stacktrace for the exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1999)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:709)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at com.safebook.MailMessage.send(MailMessage.java:144)
    at com.safebook.MailMessage.send(MailMessage.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:280)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSGlobalObject$GlobalMethod.call(FBSGlobalObject.java:219)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:448)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.initBeforeContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1621)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:333)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:521)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:26)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:340)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:367)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:32)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:480)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1994)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.yc.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.yc.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.yc.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineGenerateKey(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.b(kb.java:114)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:138)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:113)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:120)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.t(kb.java:227)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:425)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:675)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:669)
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is going wrong in the JDK's SSL support.  Perhaps something about the certificate from the server is confusing it.  You're using a pretty old version of the JDK.  I would try upgrading to a current version to see if that resolves the problem.  You can also try enabling some of the low level SSL debugging output in the JDK, as described in the links in the JavaMail [SSLNOTES.txt](http://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that Java 6 has issues with SSL, especially because TLS > 1.0 is not supported. However, since I can send mails via SMTPS I wondered why it wouldn't work with SMTP+STARTTLS. I thought that using STARTTLS just means that there is an unencrypted negotiation about whether or not to use SSL, and if both sides agree, the subsequent data transfer is encrypted just as it would be with SMPTS. Obviously, it's not that simple...

Comment: I have executed the exact same sending routine with Java 7, and it works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help, and in general thanks to you (and your fellow JavaMail developers) for providing the community with such a great mailing library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your JavaMail lib (mail.jar or javax.mail.jar) is too old.
Download the newest version from here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/